# print out the class parameters on python

Tags: python, attributes, inspect

```
class FooTable(Base):

    Id = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(256), nullable=False)
    username = Column(VARCHAR(256), nullable=False)
    state = Column(VARCHAR(100), nullable=False)
    city = Column(VARCHAR(256), nullable=False)
    zip = Column(VARCHAR(100), nullable=False)
```

I want to print out the instantiation arguments of class Column. generally- python code to string. example:

```
for k, v in vars(FooTable).iteritems():
      print k, get_class_attr(v)


>>> Id ["BIGINT", "primary_key=True"]
>>> name ["VARCHAR(256)", "nullable=False"]
    ...
```

I tried the inspect module, but found that it does not support it:
http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers

Thanks for any information

Comment: Is it sqlalchemy? Do you want to get: `FooTable.__table__.columns._data` (but without accessing private attributes)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using **`__dict__`** and then filterting its output as **dir** won't work with metaclasses either.

```
def filterFunction(field):
    '''
    This is a sample filtering function
    '''
    name, value = field
    return not name.startswith("_")

for k, v in vars(FooTable).iteritems():
      print k, filter(filterFunction, v.__dict__.items())
```

For that case for the following class

```
class X():
  foo = "bar"
  baz = True
```

Our filter

```
filter(filterFunction, X.__dict__.items())
```

would return

```
[('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', True)]
```

To get instantiation parameters, i'd check whether field name is in `Column.__init__.im_self`

Comment: Please read again the edited question. The OP wants to know the instantiation parameters.

Comment: aded corresponding change below the answer

Comment: Still nope. The OP wants to know the *actual* arguments that were passed at runtime on the class' constructor's. Not the constructors arguments neither the instance's attributes.

Comment: By getting instance's `__dict__`, you will get _actual_ _runtime_ argument names and values

Comment: So you're saying that when having a constructor like `def __init__(self, a, *args):` and I instantiate the class like `f = Foo(5, 42)`, I will see the *42* inside the instance's `__dict__`. Without storing it as an attribute instance. Could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you are asking for, doesn't make much sense. Burhan Khalid's answer is close, but not really. You want the **actual** arguments that the caller passed when instantiating
the class. Not the function's/constructor's signature.

But this is book keeping that the class' programmer should do on his own. And even then,
he wouldn't actually do that. He would `configure` each instance **based** on the passed 
parameters.

e.g.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_cool = kwargs.get('whatever', False)
```

And then I would check the instance attribute:

```
f = Foo()
f.is_cool   # False
```

and I would try to make sense of it, depending on what this means for my instance.

But I don't really care about the actual parameters passed. My instance will
configure itself **based on** what was passed.

You could of course write a class decorator that wraps any 3rd party Class and do
exactly what you need, but it is an overhead that doesn't seem justifiable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the attributes of a class with:

```
print dir( Column )
```

This is if I correctly understand your question

Comment: sorry, not the attributes, the parameters on the calling to the class

Answer (score 0):

`attrs = [i for i in dir(obj) if not i.startswith('_')]`

Keep in mind that attributes that begin with `_` are generally considered "private". Here is a sample run:

```
>>> [i for i in dir(4) if not i.startswith('_')]
['conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
>>> [i for i in dir('') if not i.startswith('_')]
['capitalize', 'center', ... 'split', 'splitlines', ... 'upper', 'zfill']
>>> class Foo:
...    a = 'Hello'
...    def __init__(self):
...      pass
...    def hello(self):
...      print 'Hello'
...
>>> [i for i in dir(Foo) if not i.startswith('_')]
['a', 'hello']
```

Comment: I mean in case a = column('foo', 'baz') and column is class, and I want to get the 'foo' and 'baz'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def bar(a,b,c):
...       pass
...
>>> x = Foo()
>>> x.bar.func_code.co_varnames
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Here is another attempt, and I think this does what you need; although its a bit convoluted.

```
>>> class Foo:
...    a = 'b'
...    def bar(y,z):
...       pass
... 

>>> funcs = [(i,getattr(Foo,i).func_code.co_varnames) for i in dir(Foo) \
...          if hasattr(getattr(Foo,i),'func_code')]
>>> 
>>> funcs
[('bar', ('y', 'z'))]
```

However if you want to know what arguments were passed to a class, then from the *instance*, use `__dict__`.

```
>>> class Foo:
...    a = ''
...    def __init__(self, b, c):
...        self.a = b
...        self.c = c
... 
>>> funcs = [(i,getattr(Foo,i).func_code.co_varnames) for i in dir(Foo) if hasattr(getattr(Foo,i),'func_code')]
>>> funcs
[('__init__', ('self', 'b', 'c'))]
>>> i = Foo(1,2)
>>> i.__dict__
{'a': 1, 'c': 2}
```